# XPath: using or

Tags: xpath

I need to find elements on a dynamic website that contain either `test.gif` or `test2.gif`. Tt my be that one of those is not present. Whats the correct synax to do it? My take with:

```
'.//*[@src="http://test/test1.gif"] or .//*[@src="http://test/test2.gif"]'
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your syntax looks fine. But perhaps you are calling it from an API where the result of the XPath expression is expected to be a node-set, whereas your expression is returning a boolean?

Comment: @ Michael Kay -- using python lxml lib, i will try to find out, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with:

```
@src="http://test/test1.gif" or @src="http://test/test2.gif"
```